# Number manipulation in python

Tags: python, excel

I new to scripting language. I have an excel (xls,2003) file which has following number

```
2      48
3      49
6      57
11     89
19     120
29     110
32     105
```

I am trying to do following

1. Read the excel file : Which I did
2. Find the difference between two consecutive number in column-2 in positive and negative sense.
3. Find the corresponding number in column-1 when the difference is maximum in positive or negative sense in column-2 defined by step-2.

I have following script done for reading excel file but I am not sure how to proceed

```
import xlrd

myexcel = xlrd.open_workbook('sample.xls')
#print "WorkSheets:", myexcel.sheet_by_names()
sheet = myexcel.sheet_by_index(0)

c = sheet.col_values(1)
print c

#data = [] #make a data store
```

I am expecting to following print

Max positive difference :11

Max negative difference :29

Comment: Please provide example output.

Comment: So, you want `6,11`? As 89 - 57 is the largest.

Comment: Output should look like :

Comment: Maximum negative difference =29

Comment: 19 is not the max difference, it should be 11. Right?

Comment: Max positive difference :11

Comment: Please delete unwanted comments and update your question with the output data.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
col1 = [2, 3, 6, 11, 19, 29, 32]
col2 = [48, 49, 57, 89, 120, 110, 105]

pd, nd, pi, ni = 0, 0, -1, -1
for i in range(len(col2)-1):
    d = col2[i+1] - col2[i]
    if d > 0 and d > pd:
        pd, pi = d, i
    if d < 0 and abs(d) > nd:
        nd, ni = abs(d), i

print "Max positive difference :" + str(col1[pi+1])
print "Max negative difference :" + str(col1[ni+1])
```

Output:

```
>>> 
Max positive difference :11
Max negative difference :29
```

---

**Update** : Short version

```
col1 = [2, 3, 6, 11, 19, 29, 32]
col2 = [48, 49, 57, 89, 120, 110, 105]

m = [(x[1] - x[0]) for x in zip(col2[:1] + col2, col2 + col2[-1:])]

print "Max positive difference :" + str(col1[m.index(max(m))])
print "Max negative difference :" + str(col1[m.index(min(m))])
```

Comment: ATOZTOA,Thanks for quick help. I really appreciate it.I am very new to coding.  Just wondering how do I put the data in the format you have used . I am pulling data from excel file using xlrd.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something like what your looking for

```
(max_pos_difference, max_pos_row_col_1_value, neg_row_col_1_value, max_neg_row_col_1_value) = get_max_row()

print "Pos val: {} Pos row: {} Neg val: {} Neg row: {}".format(max_pos_difference, max_pos_row_col_1_value, neg_row_col_1_value, max_neg_row_col_1_value)

def get_max_row():
    max_pos_difference = 0
    max_neg_difference = 0
    max_pos_row = 0
    max_neg_row = 0
    for rownum in range(sheet.nrows):
        if rownum <= sheet.nrows - 1:
            this_row_value = sheet.cell(rownum, 1).value
            next_row_value = sheet.cell(rownum+1, 1).value
            difference = next_row_value - this_row_value

        if difference > max_pos_difference and difference >= 0:
            max_pos_difference = difference
            max_pos_row = rownum

        if difference < max_neg_difference and difference < 0:
            max_neg_difference = difference
            max_neg_row = rownum

    return (max_pos_difference, sheet.cell(max_pos_row, 0).value, max_neg_difference, sheet.cell(max_neg_row, 0).value
```

Comment: Hi Wadester, it looks like there is some issue. I am getting invalid syntax for &&

Comment: Replaced && by 'and'  and it passes syntax error but complier does not like the last line . It gives following error

Comment: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: There is a typo in last line max_rom should be max_row. It still gives IdentationError.

Comment: There is an extra space before the return. Have edited. I didnt get to actually try this in an interpreter, only did it on SO so apologies but it should be OK now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this without excessive use of local variables, loops and conditions:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

col1 = [2, 3, 6, 11, 19, 29, 32]
col2 = [48, 49, 57, 89, 120, 110, 105]

difs = [ (a, c - b) for a, b, c in zip (col1 [1:], col2, col2 [1:] ) ]
print (max (difs, key = lambda x: x [1] ) [0] )
print (max (difs, key = lambda x: -x [1] ) [0] )
```

Comment: I am wondering how do I format the data coming from the excel to the way you have used.

Comment: Reading your code, I guess wit something like `col1 = sheet.col_values(1)` and `col2 = sheet.col_values(2)`. But I do not know the API; this is just an educated guess.